# Am I hitting the stl::pair issue 2051 if I use a function pointer as the value a pair?

Tags: c++, std, std-pair, keyvaluepair

I want to have a `std::unordered_map<std::string,MyClass*()>` variable. But - when I try instantiating that, I get an error message, deep inside, which is essentially:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h(102): error: a function type is not allowed here
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "std::pair<_T1, _T2> [with _T1=const std::string, _T2=MyClass *()]"
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't due to a bug of mine. I've browsed around the site and noticed a link to [LWG issue 2051](http://wg21.link/lwg2051)
making `std::pair` too restrictive. Is that really what I'm seeing? If so, what should I do to work around it? Use a wrapper class no data and  `operator()` maybe? `std::function`?

Comment: To be clear, you want to map from string to pointer-to-function-taking-no-arguments-and-returning-pointer-to-MyClass ?  If so, then change the second argument to `MyClass *(*)()`

Comment: I don't see how issue 2051 is related

Comment: I don't think a container of functions is legal - [container.requirements.general] says that contains store *objects*.  So to implement a container of functions you actually have to have a container of function pointers (or a class that wraps a function pointer, like `std::function`, or functor objects).

Comment: @M.M: FIxed that. Now I'll go look if that problem isn't actually in my code somewhere.

Comment: your error message doesn't correspond to your code... `_T2` would not be `MyClass *()` in the updated code. If you still have trouble then post a MCVE.   [Working example](http://goo.gl/EoiHqS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a map from a string to a `MyClass` pointer, you have to declare:

```
 std::unordered_map<std::string,MyClass*> x;
```

But if you want to have a map to a **function pointer** to a function returning a pointer to `MyClass` you could consider:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,MyClass*(*)()> x;
```

Comment: WIll check to see if that was the issue or if I just misquoted the definition (there's some `using = ` involved which I've removed).